# Collection meta data

Tags: json, backbone.js, model-view-controller

My server returns following JSON:

```
{
"total":100,
"posts":[//an array contains 10 posts.]
}
```

Using backbone default api, the url of a collection should return an array of models. What is proper way to send the total number of post to a view that use such collection?

Comment: Heads up, I removed the regex tags and added backbone tag.

Comment: You already have a `parse` method to unwrap `posts`, right?

Comment: @muistooshort I tried to use `parse` method before asking. It help to retrieve `posts` attribute, but I also need to use `total` in my views.

Comment: Maybe start with `this.total = response.total` in your `parse`, then adjust your `toJSON` to include the `total` somewhere to make it easy for the view (or use a `serialize` method in place of `toJSON` for feeding data to the view).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
parse: function(response){
  this.total = response.total;
  return response.posts;
}
```

Comment: First argument of `set` expect a model. The collection does not support attributes.

Comment: Oops, edited my answer. You can access the total with `myCollection.total`.